# Direct sum of Kernel Transpose and Image

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Hi I am having trouble understanding a math assigment.

The assigment is:

If A is a mxn-matrix Show that:

$$
 Im(A) ⨁ Ker(A^T) =R^n 
$$

I have no clue where to start, can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $R^m$?

Comment: Note that $(im(A))^\perp = \ker(A^T)$

Comment: @Bernard, not according to the assigment.

Comment: An $m\times n$ matrix defines a linear mapping `from` $R^n$ `to` $R^m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in\Bbb R^m$, then

$$x\in\ker A^T\iff \forall y\in\Bbb R^n \; \langle A^Tx,y\rangle=0\iff \forall y\in\Bbb R^n \; \langle x,Ay\rangle=0\iff x\in(\operatorname{Im} A)^\perp$$
hence we proved that

$$\ker A^T=(\operatorname{Im} A)^\perp$$
and the result follows if we know that in finite dimensional space and for all subspace $F$ for $\Bbb R^n$:

$$F\oplus F^\perp=\Bbb R^n$$

Comment: So the image spans the entirity of R^n?
$$
(Im(A))^⊥ ⊕ Im(A) = R^n ? 
$$

How?

Comment: No! The image spans the entirety of $\Bbb R^n$ if $(\operatorname{Im} A)^\perp=\{0\}$ which equivalent to $\ker A^T=\{0\}$.